# Prometheus query equivalent to SQL DISTINCT

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have multiple Prometheus instances providing the same metric, such as:

```
my_metric{app="foo", state="active",   instance="server-1"}  20
my_metric{app="foo", state="inactive", instance="server-1"}  30
my_metric{app="foo", state="active",   instance="server-2"}  20
my_metric{app="foo", state="inactive", instance="server-2"}  30
```

Now I want to display this metric in a Grafana singlestat widget. When I use the following query...

```
sum(my_metric{app="foo", state="active"})
```

...it, of course, sums up all values and returns `40`. So I tell Prometheus to sum it by instance...

```
sum(my_metric{app="foo", state="active"}) by (instance)
```

...which results in a "Multiple Series Error" in Grafana. Is there a way to tell Prometheus/Grafana to only use the first of the results?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a distinct, but I think this would work too:

```
topk(1, my_metric{app="foo", state="active"} by (instance))
```

Check out the second to last example in here:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/

Comment: When I execute this in Prometheus' graph UI, I get only one result. So, it looks good. But when I pass the same String to Grafana Singlestat, it still tells me "Multiple Series Error". Confusing.

Comment: That is weird it works in Prometheus but not Grafana. Could you try removing the by(instance) part?

Comment: Don't think this is valid query. You can't have `by` without using any aggregation function, like `sum`, `avg`, `max`, min`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

One way I just found is to additionally do an average over all values:

```
avg(sum(my_metric{app="foo", state="active"}) by(instance))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return an arbitrary time series out of multiple matching time series, then this can be done with [topk()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk) or [bottomk()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#bottomk) functions. For example, the following query returns a single time series with the maximum value out of multiple time series which match `my_metric{app="foo", state="active"}`:

```
topk(1, my_metric{app="foo", state="active"})
```

You need to set [instant query](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#instant-queries-in-dashboards) option in Grafana when using `topk()`. Otherwise `topk(1, ...)` may return multiple time series when it is used for building a graph with range query. This is because `topk(1, ...)` selects a single time series with the max value individually per each point on the graph. Different points on the graph may have different time series with the max value. There is a workaround, which allows returning a single series out of many series on a graph in alternative Prometheus-like systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). It provides `topk_*` and `bottomk_*` functions for this purpose. See, for example, [topk_last](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_last) or [topk_avg](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_avg).

Note that `topk()` has no common grounds with `DISTINCT` from SQL. If you need to select distinct label values with PromQL, then you need to use `count(...) by (label)`. It will return unique label values for the given `label` alongside the number of unique time series per each label value.  For example, `count(my_metric) by (app)` will return unique `app` label names for time series with `my_metric` name. This is roughly equivalent to the following SQL with `DISTINCT` clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT app FROM my_metric
```

See [count() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count) for details.